# What is the best way to store duration in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store duration  (number of minutes and/or hours and/or days).
I have looked at MySQL type, but DATE and TIME types seems to be used to store a specific date in time. Not a duration.

I thinking about using a int to store the number of second, and convert it in the PHP for display.

Comment: The mysql `TIME` range is '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. Whether or not it's a good fit probably depends on how you are using the data. I've used it for storing things like MP3 song length, etc.

Comment: The approach you are thinking of is good.

Comment: How do you want to use that duration information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have the answer yourself. You can store the number of milliseconds(or any unit) in the duration as a number and convert it to the unit that you wish in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value as a number.

Answer (score -1):

You might not necessarily need to store it, either, if it's being calculated from data already in your table you could run a math query: SELECT time1-time2 FROM table_name

Comment: I tough about it, but I really need to store a duration.